# Dynamically loaded (pluginable) components with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, plugins, components

I have a vue.js application. I compile this application and publish it through a web server.

Later, I'd like to build and publish additional components that can be dynamically loaded by the main application at runtime in a way plugins may work on "standard" desktop applications. This means that these plugins will be compiled and provided by the same server, but the main application will not be aware of the specific plugins at compilation time, just looking for them in a folder.

I think this may be more related to the application packager and provider (webpack?) than vue.js itself, but I couldn't find any information to start.

How could I achieve this ?

May be related to : [Vue.js dynamic component with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801950/vue-js-dynamic-component-with-webpack)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: No, but maybe you find something now that Vue is using Vite instead of Webpack as a package bundler